# Removing outlier documents from corpus

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

How can I  remove outlier documents from corpus before passing it to  LDA ?

I am doing topic modeling using LDA.I have a large source of data from different websites. I want to classify them into 5 categories but the presence of outlier documents give inaccurate results.

Can anyone please help with this issue.I want only those articles related to any 5 categories to be present after classification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a subset of your current dataset as input in your model. Are there particular characteristics of the articles that are outliers? If, for example, the length of some articles are too long, you could subset by:

```
corpus = corpus[corpus['text'].str.len() < 1000]
```

Or, if you find some outliers manually, you could delete them manually by:

```
corpus = corpus[corpus['title'] != 'Stackoverflow saved my life']
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: throw out words that are so frequent that they tell us little about the topic as well as words that are too infrequent appearing in < 15 rows then keep 100,000 words off the top

```
dictionary_15.filter_extremes(no_below=15, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000)
```

Hard way: If you only want documents within a certain topic you can build a two layer LDA which first allocates topics generally then build a second lda by filtering those documents classified in the first layer to your target topic and allocating.  I would build an LDA with say five topics output them into a csv then create a new doc by sorting and filtering in Alteryx or even excel might be easier than python and using that document to perform the second step.